# Unable to resolve the source file. magento 2 admin sales order grid

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, grid, order-grid

In admin. We are getting this error open SALES=>Orders.

```
Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/collection' #0 /var/www/abc.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile() #1 /var/www/abc.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch() #2 /var/www/abc.com/pub/static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource)) #3 {main}
```

I have tried 
Delete all folder in pub/static/ expect .htaccess.
Run command: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy